# Почему так происходит?

Tags: php, json

Вот что должен отвечать сервер в результате ошибки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вместо этого он вот чем отвечает: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все нормально, так кодирует `JSON` символы юникода (их коды), чтобы убрать, есть второй параметр:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` - Не кодировать многобайтные символы `Unicode` (по умолчанию они кодируются как \uXXXX). Доступно начиная с `PHP 5.4.0`

---

Решение для **Laravel**, комментарий от [Venta](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221007/venta):

```
return response()->json($msg, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что это Laravel, правильнее будет `return response()->json($msg, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` Вот расшифровка функции 

    `JsonResponse json(string|array $data = [], int $status = 200, array $headers = [], int $options)`